# SoX batch convert adding white noise

Tags: macos, audio, terminal, sox, whitenoise

I'm trying to add white noise to hundreds of files. I find a command but don't know how to adapt it.
There is a source folder with files and an empty destination folder. Could someone help me with the right command?
I'm using OSX.

http://linguistics.berkeley.edu/plab/guestwiki/index.php?title=Sox_in_phonetic_research#Add_noise_to_an_audio_file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the command in a `for` loop, then refer to the `for` variable as file name.

I assume that the source folder and the destination folder are on the same level.

```
for file in *.wav; do sox "$file" -p synth whitenoise vol 0.02 | sox -m "$file" - "../DESTINATION/$file"; done
```

In addition, if you want to use a suffix in the name of the output files, use `basename` to exclude the extension:

```
for file in *.wav; do sox "$file" -p synth whitenoise vol 0.02 | sox -m "$file" - "../DESTINATION/$(basename $file)_output.wav"; done
```